# Interpolating a matlab colormap

Tags: matlab, interpolation, colormap

In Matlab, using a predefined colormap, I want to associate a color triplet to any value in a range [v_min , v_max].

How can I interpolate this colormap ?

Answer (score 5):

The following code will do. Note that you need to scale and offset the variable you are plotting from `[vmin vmax]` to `[0 1]`

```
val % Variable scaled correctly to the colormap scale (0-1).

hsv=rgb2hsv(cmap);
cm_data=interp1(linspace(0,1,size(cmap,1)),hsv,val);
cm_data=hsv2rgb(cm_data);
```

`cm_data` should have the triplet you are looking for. Code taken from [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51986-perceptually-uniform-colormaps)

Note: This will do what you ask, but I am not sure if you want to do this. If this is for plotting purposes, it is a bad idea, as the colormap needs to increase linearly with data, and MATLABs color plotting will assume it is.

If your objective is to make sure you have enough a big colormap then change `val` to `linspace(0,1,300)`.

Comment: You can use `interp1` on a 2D matrix.  Each column would be interpolated independently.  That's actually how the parula colour map is interpolated in MATLAB.... so you can simply do `cm_data = interp1(linspace(0,1,size(cmap,1)), hsv, val);`

Comment: @rayryeng oh dang, I didnt know!

Comment: No problem :) I found that out by accident when looking at the `parula.m` source!